# Problem with creating shorcuts in ubuntu

Tags: .desktop

I am new to Linux. I tried to create shorcuts in linux ubuntu but my terminal shows this message everytime. Can anyone explain what is the problem.

It says:gnome-desktop-item-edit: file:///root/Desktop does not have a .desktop or .directory suffix

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with your Ubuntu default language which is different from English.

Instead of ~/Desktop use the default language expression, listing your root folder.

In my case, Portuguese I did:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit -–create-new ~/Área\ de\ Trabalho/
```

It works

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create shortcuts is this: Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

When the installation is done, type this command at the prompt.

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit -–create-new ~/Desktop
```

Once you type the command above, a windows will open with the new shortcut properties:

[image]

Just choose the type, type in the name,command, and any comments that you like, and click OK.  An example is shown below:

[image]

[image]