# Problem with gnome-desktop-item-edit on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, launcher, .desktop

I build the launch application with

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/.desktop --create-new
```

How to show it

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[de_DE]=/home/linuxx/MediathekView-latest-linux/MediathekView.svg
Name[de_DE]=aaaaa
Exec=/home/linuxx/MediathekView-latest-linux/MediathekView.sh
Name=aaaaa
Icon=/home/linuxx/MediathekView-latest-linux/MediathekView.svg
```

My problem is with the step later... I try that this application shows on my Desktop, I tried as other people [say](https://askubuntu.com/a/290596), but it's not working...

Comment: You have created a desktop entry a.k.a. shortcut with `.desktop` name. Since it starts with `.`, it is most probably hidden. If you want to see the content, run `cat ~/.local/share/applications/.desktop`

Comment: @ Kulfy thanks for you answer , but a found the solution , i will now answer my Question...

Comment: That's a great thing and highly encouraged :)

Answer (score 0):

I know how to does it...

1- In top above left on the corner on icon click to **activities**.

2- on the window **"Type to search..."**, write **aaaaa** (the Programe Name..)

3- On the icon from **aaaaa** with the right Mause, give to add it,

How to have it on my desktop

[image: My Application on Desktop]

The Application is **MV**

Very Thanks all your for the help and **SurvivalMachine** for your correction...

I wish you a nice day!